# Indy - Know when modem has sent a RESET [RST] flag

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy10

I have noticed that I receive an EIdSocketError with LastError = 10054 or 10053 when the device I'm talking to sends a RESET response.  Which makes sense, given 10054 is Connection Reset By Peer.

So is there anything I can check in Indy to determine if this has ocurred rather than wrapping my code in try/except block and looking for 10054 or 10053 error codes?

One scenario I encountered was the modem replied with a RESET reply after I connected (Indy didn't raise an exception) so from my point of view the connection succeeded.  I then attempted to write to the socket (ie send a packet using TidTCPClient) and the 10054 error was raised.

Is it possible to see this RESET reply at all?

Thanks

Comment: from what I know, you need to wrap it in a try...except, that's how Indy "knows that something went wrong", i.e. connection dropped, reseted, etc.

Comment: What kind of "RESET reply" is it exactly?  Are you talking about a low-level TCP reset, or a protocol-level reset message?

Comment: @Remy - I don't know to be honest.  I believe it's the RST flag for TCP. Along the lines of SYN, ACK, PSH etc.  Not sure if that answers your question though?  "Often" I'll see a response of [RST, ACK] in the flag, but the error seems when [RST] flag is set by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `try..except` is the right way. Indy communicates throught exceptions. Even 'Connection closed gracefully' is an exception in Indy's eyes.

Comment: `EIdConnClosedGracefully` is only raised if you try to read/write data after the other party has already disconnected on their end, though.