# how I can handle idhttp error?

Tags: delphi, indy

How I can avoid any interrupt in my application that Get a webpage HTML with idHTTP? because my application must gets some data in cycle of time automatically and save it for using with another application, and when this application stopped with an error and waiting for user to press OK button in error message box, it make a big problem for me...

I want to dismiss any error and retry `idHTTP.get()` when those errors occurred.

most of errors that occurs in my application is 'connection closed gracefully' and sometimes 'Host unreachable'.

Regards

Comment: The answer what you need to implement [`is here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9804496/960757).

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the `idHttp.get` call in a `try except` clause, more here: [Handling Exceptions in Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25665)